# Question about .htaccess 301 routing An exception 301 routing is in the .htaccess file

Tags: http-status-code-301, .htaccess

I have the following command:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

The command redirects to the same address and removes the slash.

For example:
http://example.com/folder/

Will be redirected to:
http://example.com/folder

I want to add an exception where routing will not work. If the user specifically enters the following address:
https://example.com/a/b/
Then there will be no routing - but only at that specific address.

Does anyone have an idea? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this /a/b/ except in the rule

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/a/b/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```